# Pulsed plane wave

Tags: plane-wave

My question is specifically concerned with ultrashort pulses: can a plane wave (one with infinite spatial extension) have a finite duration in time? Is there some physical principle that is violated for a pulsed plane wave?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, a plane wave has infinite spatial and time extension. By Fourier analysis, it thus has one unique frequency and wavelenght.

If you make it finite in space and/or time (like in a pulse), its spectrum broadens with new frequencies and wavelenghts and it is no longer what we call a "plane wave".

To awnser your comment, the argument is just that by the principle of superposition your different waves will indeed propagate at the same speed, but the "whole object" won't be called a plane wave stricto sensu because it doesn't have a well-defined unique frequency.
If the different frequencies form a continuum, the wave interfere with each other to create a finite-size wave that reduces to a pulse if the continuum is very large. I think your understanding is right, it is just a matter of definition of what call a plane wave.

Comment: I was actually thinking that a collection of monochromatic plane waves could be propagating in vacuum as a whole object (since all of the frequencies will have the same velocity), but I had a conversation with a colleague that claims otherwise, however without giving any arguments. This has made me think if there is some other constraint to the existence of a pulsed plane wave...